# Which one step checkout type extensions honour original layout handle?

Tags: checkout, layout, magento-1, onestepcheckout

One of my extensions uses the below layout xml instruction to add a common block for three payment methods to the checkout

```
<checkout_onepage_paymentmethod>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="additional" as="additional">
            <block type="foomandpspro/pxpostrebill_ccSave" name="fooman_ccsave" as="fooman_ccsave"
                   template="fooman/dpspro/onePageCheckout.phtml"/>
        </block>    
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_paymentmethod>
```

This works without a problem on the default checkout.

**The problem:** A lot of my users are using one of the myriads of one step checkouts which are not honoring this. The layout handle is simply not loaded and subsequently the block is not added to the page. So far I have encountered MW_Onestepcheckout and GoMage_Checkout.

Have you come across any custom checkout extensions that actually handle this correctly? Or is this a case where I need to accept that the checkout layout handles have been retired and I need to `start repeating myself`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It unfortunately looks like there isn't much out there. For now I have dissolved my custom block and moved the functionality into the individual `Mage_Payment_Block_Form` blocks until support for this becomes more commonplace.

Answer (score 1):

I think checkout_onepage is ONEPAGE therefore, you have to handle the others, the same way, with their own handles.

I don't think there is any global layout handle, like `catalog_category_layered_nochildren` or `PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable` in the checkout, at least `addHandle()` is not used anywhere in `Mage_Checkout`, `Mage_Payment` or `Mage_Sales`.

Comment: thanks for your response - the question was more about 3rd party extensions not written by me. I was hoping that the ones I encountered that take away functionality of the original checkout are in the minority. But so far it doesn't look good.